# Type 'Map<string, any>' is not an array type or a string type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Adding lib "ES2015" or higher solves every other type issue for typescript compilation with target ES5, but Map just doesn't want to work.

How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to add `downlevelIteration` to compilerOptions:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "lib": [ "DOM", "ES2015" ],
  "downlevelIteration": true,
  ...
},
```

Comment: More info https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#downlevelIteration